# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the following.... in PL/SQL script

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
create or replace function lstnation (listdisplay in varchar2)
return varchar2 is
    nName varchar2 (1000) default null;
    listD varchar2(1000) default null;
    
    cursor display_nation
    is
            select nation.n_name 
            from nation
            inner join region
            on region.r_regionkey = nation.n_nationkey
            where region.r_regionname = listdisplay;
BEGIN
    open display_nation;
    loop
    fetch display_nation into nName;
        exit when display_nation%notfound;
        IF
           listD := listD || RTRIM(nName)||' , ';
    end loop;
    close display_nation;
    return listD;
end lstnation;
/
DECLARE 
    rKey region.r_regionkey%type;
    rName region.r_name%type;
    nList varchar2(1000);
    cursor outer_block is 
        select region.r_regionkey, region.r_name, lstnation(region.r_name)
        from region;
BEGIN
    open outer_block;
        loop
            fetch outer_block into rKey, rName, nList;
        exit when outer_block%notfound;
        dbms.output.put_line(rkey || ' ' || RTRIM(rName) || ': '|| nList);
         end loop;
         close outer_block;
end;
/
```

I get two errors, how can I fix it

LINE/COL ERROR

---

19/12    PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the
following:
. ( * @ % & = - + < / > at in is mod remainder not rem then
<an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2
like4 likec between || multiset member submultiset

20/2     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the
following:
begin function pragma procedure subtype type 
 current cursor delete
exists prior

Comment: I think perhaps a title with "PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol" could help others finding this post.

Comment: You have an IF keyword an no condition.

Comment: The error is in your function code, not any script.

Answer (score 0):

You can save some coding and efficiency by replacing the cursor loop with the [listagg](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030) function

```
    select listagg(rtrim(nation.n_name),',')
    from nation
    inner join region
    on region.r_regionkey = nation.n_nationkey
    where region.r_regionname = listdisplay;
```

So that will collate all the matching rows, and use whatever delimiter is passed in. One thing to be aware of, you have  `listD varchar2(1000)`  so as long as the results from the query are less than 1000, you are OK.  If you expect a larger result set, you may need to increase or use a clob.

If for some reason, you still want to use the loop method, then you need to fix your IF statement:

```
loop
    fetch display_nation into nName;
        exit when display_nation%notfound;
        IF <condition> THEN
           listD := listD || RTRIM(nName)||' , ';
        END IF;
    end loop;
```